# How to open multiple instances of Filemaker's Inspector window?

Tags: filemaker

Is there a way to open multiple simultaneous instances of Filemaker's Inspector window? In my case, screen real-estate is more abundant than time.

Answer (score 1):

In **Layout Mode**:

Go to the **View** menu, select "**New Inspector**"